# When buying imperial bux on Star Wars it's not crediting my game?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've done it 3 times now it's directing me to the confirmation page but going back into the game, the imperial bux are not credited

Answer (score 1):

Could you please specify the amount of time that has passed since this happened?

This can often happen when servers are backed up on requests, but if it has taken more than two hours or so this may be a completely different problem and merit a call to customer support.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a windows phone, follow the support link in the receipt email from Microsoft.  They credited me when I had the same thing.